# How to optimize a Python for loop to make it run faster

Tags: python, optimization, raspberry-pi, led

I'm trying to multiplex an array of 63 RGB leds using an overlocked ("Turbo" mode) Raspberry Pi and two MCP23017 i2c port expanders. The issue I'm having is that the leds flicker a lot.

Each led is basically three leds in one with a common anode. As such, I'm treating them as separate leds. So instead of 63 leds I effectively have 189 leds in a 14x14 matrix. It's created by:

```
pin_array=[[0]*14 for i in range(14)]
```

Each entry in the matrix is then filled with either a 1 indicating the led should be on or a 0 if it should be off. To cycle through turning each led on/off I use the following code:

```
#Example continous loop
while (1==1):
    #Cycle through pins and turn on/off appropriate LEDs
    for row_index, row in enumerate(pin_array):
        #Power on row
        mcp1.output(row_index,1) #for mcp1 a value of 1 is On
        for col_index, column in enumerate(row):
            #If the value is 1 turn on the LED then turn it off
            if column==1:
                mcp2.output(col_index,0) #for mcp2 a value of 0 is On
                mcp2.output(col_index,1)
        #Power off row
        mcp1.output(row_index,0)
```

Is there any way to improve/optimize the above code to make it run faster so the flickering goes away?

**Update:** I've tried using some of the optimizations and suggestions given by zero.zero.seven,  user2357112, and kindall and ended up with this:

```
last_row=13
last_col=13
while 1:
    row=0
    #Cycle through pins and turn on/off appropriate LEDs
    while row<14:
        col=0
        #Power on row
        mcp1.output(row,1) #for mcp1 a value of 1 is On
        while col<14:
            if pin_array[row][col]==1:
                mcp2.output(last_col,1) #for mcp2 a value of 0 is On
                mcp2.output(col,0)
                last_row=row
                last_col=col
            col+=1
        mcp1.output(row,0)
        row+=1
```

The only method I have to judge flickering is by eye sadly. To my eye there wasn't any noticeable change in the flickering with the optimizations and change in activation schedule.

Comment: use True instead of 1==1
and use basic "for" loops, enumerations are not so fast

Comment: I don't think the flickering is because your code isn't running fast enough. It looks more like you should change the way you schedule the activations and deactivations. Perhaps turn each LED on before turning the previous one off.

Comment: Could you tell us how do you want to turn on/off LEDs? The problem is probably  in the calls to `output` and the fact that it takes much more time to turn on/off a LED than doing anything else in that code. Probably it would be better to turn on/off the LEDs in a different sequence to remove the flickering.

Comment: @Bakuriu  I don't quite understand what you mean by how I want to turn them on/off or using a different sequence. My apologies I'm learning as I go. I have the 63 RGB LEDs at various locations on a map and the goal is to have them show either red, green, or blue continuously for each location based on certain criteria. I'm using the MCP23017s as the method to turn them on/off. The `output` [command](http://learn.adafruit.com/mcp230xx-gpio-expander-on-the-raspberry-pi/using-the-library) is the only method I know of to use the i2c expanders for this purpose.

Comment: What I mean is that LED's takes time to turn on/off, and your code should be aware of this. For example: try to give more time to the LEDs to turn on putting a `time.sleep(0.1)` just before the `mcp1.output(row, 0)`. Try to increase/decrease the waiting time to see if the flicker changes.

Comment: @Bakuriu Ah thank you for the clarification. I gave your suggestion a try but it seems to slow down the flicker. It effectively makes each LED blink once every several seconds. Even with a .00001 wait time it just gets closer to the flickering speed of when there is no delay. I'm more looking to speed up the flicker until it's faster than the eye can see and appears constant via persistence of vision.

Comment: Then either there is no solution or you are doing something redundant that is taking time. Can you explain clearly what's the output you want to see in the LEDs? Maybe there is a way to achieve it using less calls to `output`. I want to stress that the problem is *not* the speed of the loop, but is all about how fast are the calls to `output` and whether you are doing redundant calls.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Agreed. The video on the page the OP linked mentions a single output toggle speed of about 300 Hz (doing `while True:` `mcp.output(0, 1)` `mcp.output(0, 0)`). With such speed you can only toggle a small number of LEDs before you notice flickering.

Comment: @Bakuriu The LEDs are on a map and I want them to show a certain color based on other criteria. For example: Person A owns objective 1 so it appears red. Later Person B takes the objective so it appears blue. The LEDs should appear to be on continuously though.

Comment: @Bakuriu @moarningsun If the problem is in the `output` command it's being imported from [this file](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_MCP230xx/Adafruit_MCP230xx.py) which itself imports from [this file](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code/blob/master/Adafruit_I2C/Adafruit_I2C.py). Would it be faster to take the code sections and put them directly into my code? Is there a reference for the relative speed of various calls in Python?

Comment: The point I wanted to make is that the speed of python is *completely irrelevant*. Even if you were writing in C you'd have the same exact problem. The problem are the calls to I/O, i.e. calls to `write_word_data`/`write_byte_data` of the `smbus.SMBus` class. Writing a single byte/word is simply to slow to do what you want. You must find a way to write a bigger chunk of data to the bus or to write a smaller number of words.

Answer (score 0):

I think these are the micro optimizations you need

```
#Example continous loop
#these are optional
#pin_array_len = len(pin_array)
#i_len = len(pin_array[0])
while True:
    i = 0
    #Cycle through pins and turn on/off appropriate LEDs
    while i < 14:
        j = 0
        #Power on row
        mcp1.output(i,1) #for mcp1 a value of 1 is On
        while j < 14:
            #If the value is 1 turn on the LED then turn it off
            if pin_array[i][j]==1:
                mcp2.output(j,0) #for mcp2 a value of 0 is On
                mcp2.output(j,1)
            j += 1
        #Power off row
        mcp1.output(i,0)
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your biggest problem is that you're turning the LED off almost as soon as you've turned it on. Due to the overhead of the loop, the LED is going to spend a lot less time on than off. A way to avoid this might be to remember the last column you turned on, and turn that off before turning the next LED on, rather than the other way around.

There are also some micro-optimizations you can do. For example, instead of forcing Python to compare `1` to `1` each time through the `while` loop, just do `while True` or even `while 1` which I believe is slightly faster (since `True` is a global name that must be looked up). This won't make a big difference because that comparison doesn't happen that often.

With some trickery you might be able to write the inner loop as a generator expression. While this isn't great for readability, you might get some better performance. Also, rather than iterating with `enumerate()`, you could try pre-generating a list of row and column indices and just iterating over the indices. You will want to profile this of course to see if it's actually faster.

However, you're never going to get truly high performance from CPython. Fortunately, PyPy 2.1 runs on ARM and can be deployed on the Raspberry Pi; you might try that.

Comment: `while 1` is faster only in python2; in python3 `while 1` and `while True` produce the exact same bytecode.